# gfortran not running on OSX dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libgfortran.3.dylib

Tags: conda, gfortran, macos-catalina

I've installed miniconda3 gfortran and have set `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` to `/miniconda3/lib` in `.bash_profile`.  I've read many other answers but nothing seems to work.

```
gfortran --version
GNU Fortran (GCC) 4.8.5
```

runtime error is

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libgfortran.3.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/Liza/Desktop/family/xmas/./a.out
  Reason: image not found
```

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour]. If the other questions and answers did not apply you *really* have to give us more details. How exactly did they *"not work"*? If you want a different answer, you must tell us how your case is different. Where exactly is `libgfortran.3.dylib` present on your computer?

Comment: I would be happy to answer your questions and provide more details, but in fact your reply already pointed me quickly to the problem.  I had provided the incorrect path to libgfortran.3.dylib in my .bash_profile.  thank you very much!  Problem solved.  I no longer get a runtime error.

Answer (score 1):

One should not need to set `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` in order to use a Fortran compiler in a Conda environment, especially not setting it on a user-wide level via `.bash_profile`.

Creating an env with the Conda Forge Fortran compiler stack:

```
conda create -n foo -c conda-forge fortran-compiler
```

one can then see on activation that the environment automatically handles updating the appropriate flags to pick up the `envs/foo/lib` and `envs/foo/include` directories:

```bash
(base) $ conda activate foo
(foo) $ env | grep -E "^(FORTRAN|LD)"
LDFLAGS=-Wl,-pie -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -Wl,-dead_strip_dylibs -Wl,-rpath,/Users/mfansler/miniconda3/envs/foo/lib -L/Users/mfansler/miniconda3/envs/foo/lib
LD=x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-ld
FORTRANFLAGS=-march=core2 -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector -O2 -pipe -isystem /Users/mfansler/miniconda3/envs/foo/include
LDFLAGS_LD=-pie -headerpad_max_install_names -dead_strip_dylibs -rpath /Users/mfansler/miniconda3/envs/foo/lib -L/Users/mfansler/miniconda3/envs/foo/lib
```

For general workflow, I would recommend creating a YAML file that includes all the dependencies you require, e.g.,

**fortran-env.yaml**

```
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - fortran-compiler
  - zlib  # example dependency
```

Then create an environment from this (`conda env create -f fortran-env.yaml`), which you activate when compiling your project.